# SQL 'order by' first, and then next

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table, something like

```
STUDENTNAME   ISMANUALLYADDED   ISEDITED
-----------   ---------------   --------
APPLE              0               0
ANT                0               1
BELL               0               0
DOLL               1               0
```

Here, I am trying to sort the data by `studentname` first, by `ismanuallyadded`, and then by `isedited`. I am expecting the result like:

```
StudentName
-----------
APPLE
BELL
DOLL
ANT
```

For this, I am trying like,

```
select studentname from table1
order by studentname, ismanuallyadded, isedited
```

but, this query gives the result like,

```
Student
-------
APPLE
ANT
BELL
DOLL
```

Is it possible to order by `studentname` first and then order by `ismanuallyadded`?

I am trying to display all the studentnames (neither `manually added` nor `isedited`) alphabetically, then only `ismanuallyadded` students should come, and then `isedited`.

Comment: Please explain the logic of the expected result.

Comment: I think you're having a confusion: The first result is no ordered. There is NO ORDER on Sql queries except you specified. Your first query is a random order. Maybe is equal to the order of the data inserted, but it's just casual. The last query is ordered alphabetically, as you set with the order by..

Comment: You got your sort order wrong. What you're saying is: *Sort by studentname, and if two or more have the same studentname, sort by ismanuallyadded, and if two or have the same manuallyadded state, sort by isedited*. That doesn't match your desired result.

Comment: @MartinSmith I have updated my question. can you check that now

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The second criteria in the `order by` is only used when different rows have the same value in the previous criteria.

Your rows all have different `studentname` values, so the second and third criteria are never used.

Try this:

```
select studentname from table1
order by isedited, ismanuallyadded, studentname
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select studentname from table1
order by studentname ASC, ismanuallyadded ASC, isedited ASC
```

Comment: thanks ramesh for ur response

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result you specify, you're ordering by `ismanuallyadded` and **then** `studentname`, not the other way around.

```
select studentname from table1
order by ismanuallyadded, studentname, isedited.
```

Your current query effectively becomes: order by `studentname`, and then if `studentname` is the same for multiple rows, order by `ismanuallyadded`.

You seem to want to order by `ismanuallyadded`, and then order all rows with the same `ismanuallyadded` status by `studentname`.

Comment: I have updated my question, can just check it and help me out.

Answer (score 1):

The second field to sort by is only used when several entries are found with the same value in the first field. You don't have this case, so it should only sort by the first field (which should yield ANT before APPLE ...)

Your expected result would be achieved with the sort order
order by isedited, ismanuallyadded, studentname